# Let $\alpha$ be a root of $(x^2-a)$ and $\beta$ be a root of $(x^2-b)$. Provide conditions over $a$ and $b$ to have $F=K(\alpha+\beta)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field, positive-characteristic

**QUESTION:** Let $K$ be a field of characteristic different of $2$. Let $F$ be a splitting field for $(x^2-a)(x^2-b)\in K[x]$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^2-a$ and $\beta$ be a root of $x^2-b$. Provide conditions over $a$ and $b$ to have $F=K(\alpha+\beta)$.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{a}$, $\beta=\sqrt{b}$ and $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$.
First of all, we have $F=K(\alpha, \beta)$ due to the definition of splitting field.
Defining $K(\alpha+\beta)=K(\gamma)$.

Let's show that $K(\alpha, \beta)\subset K(\gamma)$:

- From $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$ follows that
  \begin{align*}
  \gamma^2&=(\alpha+\beta)^2\\
  &=\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta+\beta^2\\
  &=(\sqrt{a})^2+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} +(\sqrt{b})^2\\
  &=(a+b)+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\qquad (*)\\
  \end{align*}
- Now we are going to show that $\sqrt{b}\in K(\gamma)$

Indeed, multiplying both sides in $(*)$ by $\sqrt{b}$ we have:

$\gamma^2\sqrt{b}=(a+b)\sqrt{b}+2\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{b})^2$. Then $$\sqrt{b}=\frac{2b\sqrt{a}+(a+b)\sqrt{b}}{\gamma^2}\in K(\gamma)$$

- Similarly, $\sqrt{a}\in K(\gamma)$, this is

$\gamma^2\sqrt{a}=(a+b)\sqrt{a}+2(\sqrt{a})^2\sqrt{b}$, then

$$\sqrt{a}=\frac{(a+b)\sqrt{a}+2a\sqrt{b}}{\gamma^2}\in K(\gamma)$$

**MY DOUBT:**
I guess there is no conditions over $a$ and $b$ such that $\alpha=\sqrt{a}$ and $\beta=\sqrt{b}$, however I'm not sure. And I don't know how to connect this with the hypothesis that $K$ has characteristic different of two. Would you help me please?

Comment: how do you know $$\frac{2b\sqrt{a}+(a+b)\sqrt{b}}{\gamma^2}$$ is in F?

Comment: Your definitions for $K$ and $F$ are all over the place, so I'd suggest that you first fix that. Also, [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482414/general-way-to-determine-mathbbq-gamma-mathbbq-alpha-beta-given) answers a similar question in a general way, so I think it is worth looking at.

Comment: Thank you for remarks given. Sorry because I didn't asnwer yesterday, because I didn't have enough reputation. Now it is ok. So, I'm going to correct. @paulblartmathcop

Comment: Thank you for remarks given. Sorry because I didn't asnwer yesterday, because I didn't have enough reputation. @Wen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know that $[ K( \alpha,\beta ) : K ]=4$, with basis $\{1,\alpha,\beta,\alpha\beta\}$, you can proceed as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \gamma \\ \gamma^2 \\ \gamma^3 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ a+b & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & a+3b & 3a+b & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \alpha \\ \beta \\ \alpha\beta \end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix has determinant $4(b-a)$ and so is invertible iff $a\ne b$ since the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$. Therefore, $\{1,\gamma,\gamma^2,\gamma^3\}$ is also a basis and so generates the same space, that is, $K( \alpha,\beta ) = K(\gamma)=K( \alpha + \beta )$.

Bottom line: The main condition is that $[ K( \alpha,\beta ) : K ]=4$, or equivalently, $\beta \not\in K( \alpha)$.

This approach does not work in characteristic $2$ because $[K(\gamma):K]\le 2$ since $\gamma^2 = a+b \in K$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3832301/589

Comment: I would like to point out to OP that this proof can be adapted to any field of characteristic not 2. Furthermore, this proof shows why we cannot do this in characteristic 2. The determinant of this matrix was $4(b-a)$ and $4=0$ in characteristic 2, so the matrix will always be singular.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $x^2-a,x^2-b$ are irreducible over $K$ and $b\ne a$, since otherwise the problem is trivial.

- If $\sqrt{b}\not \in K(\sqrt{a})$ then **show that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ has 4 distinct conjugates** (that's where we use $char(K)\ne 2$) which implies that $[K(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}):K] = 4$.
- If $\sqrt{b}=u+v\sqrt{a} \in K(\sqrt{a})$ then $v\ne 0$ so $(u+v\sqrt{a})^2\in K$ implies $u=0$. Since $b\ne a$ then $v\ne \pm 1$ and hence $K(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})= K((v+1)\sqrt{a})=K(\sqrt{a})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! You also helped me