# If $p$, $q$ are two distinct prime numbers in $\Bbb N$ then $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p, \sqrt q)) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt p + \sqrt q)$.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

If $p$, $q$ are two distinct prime numbers in $\Bbb N$ then

$$\Bbb Q(\sqrt p, \sqrt q) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt p + \sqrt q)$$

How to prove that the first is included in the second, and why is it ligical to assume the equality

Comment: Since $\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q},\sqrt{p})$, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q},\sqrt{p})$. Showing the reverse inclusion is how you get equality.

Comment: Please use Mathjax rather than extended characters.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921711/let-alpha-be-a-root-of-x2-a-and-beta-be-a-root-of-x2-b-provide?noredirect=1#comment8087617_3921711

Look to this answer, and tell me if can help you... Is more general then your question but is regarding the same point

Comment: Your question has been asked (and answered) many times. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325514/300700 for what I think is the minimal amount of calculations.

Comment: You have been asking a lot of questions in introductory field theory. Please try to give your own thoughts/attempts and context (like which book you are studying, what are the definitions you know). Otherwise most of these questions will get closed for lack of context.

Comment: Here is a hint. $a=\sqrt{p} +\sqrt{q}, b=(p-q) /a$ are members of $\mathbb{Q} (a) $. Express $\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q} $ in terms of $a, b$ and you are done. You may as well update your question with an attempt based on this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\sqrt p$ and $b=\sqrt q$.

Let $c=(a^2+3b^2)a+(3a^2+b^2)b.$ Then $c=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3=(a+b)^3\in \Bbb Q(a+b).$

Let $d=(a^2+3b^2)(a+b).$ Then $d=(p+3q)(a+b)\in \Bbb Q(a+b).$

So $2(p-q)b=2(a^2-b^2)b=c-d\in \Bbb Q(a+b).$

So $\sqrt q=b\in \Bbb Q(a+b)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt p +\sqrt q).$

The rest is up to you.