# What are the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I would like to calculate the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$.
I know that the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ have the form of ${a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}}$, where a,b,c $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ have the form of $a+b\sqrt{3}$, where a,b $\in \mathbb{Q}$.
I also calculated the minimal polynomial of $(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ , which is: $x^6−9x^4−4x^3+27x^2−36x−23$.

Can you help me to calculate the form of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$? I have to find the elements of the linear combinations which form the higher powers of $(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$ which are also powers of $(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$?
Could you give me a proper method to find the solution? Also, could you write down your calculation in your answer? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: A while back I wrote [an answer that is relevant to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359054/constructing-a-degree-4-rational-polynomial-satisfying-f-sqrt2-sqrt3-0/359073#359073), but for the simpler example of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt 3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $\theta=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3}$ has degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q(\theta)$ is the set of polynomial expressions in $\theta$ of degree at most $5$.

Another take: $Q(\theta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3922059/589

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you give me a similar form as in the case for example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2))$? How can you prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: @mathfairy, adapt the answer linked above.

Comment: @mathfairy: You may also use primitive element theorem to prove those two fields equal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

Your problem becomes easy if $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$.
$\mathbb{Q}(\beta)\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$ ($\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$). Let's see that $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$:

$$\beta-\sqrt{3}=\sqrt[3]{2}$$
$$(\beta-\sqrt{3})^3=2$$
$$\beta^3-3\sqrt{3}\beta^2-9\beta+3\sqrt{3}=2$$
$$\sqrt{3}=(\beta^3-9\beta^2+1)/3(\beta^2-1)\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$$

Thus, $\sqrt[3]{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3})$ too, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3}) =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$.