# Find $\gamma$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-2x+3$ and $\beta$ is a root of $x^2+x+2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I have to answer the following problem:

- Find $\gamma$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-2x+3$ and $\beta$ is a root of $x^2+x+2$

I am a bit confused: How do we pick a root of each of those polynomials? If I didn't messed something, I guess they do not have roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ so what roots should we pick? Should we make two extensions so that we obtain a root for each one of them and then try to find $\gamma$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$?

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Field extension of $\gamma$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Then shouldn't the notation be $\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]$?

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar It depends on the book. Lang's book for example writes it that way.

Comment: It doesn't matter which roots you pick. The intention is to express $\gamma$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. See, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482414/general-way-to-determine-mathbbq-gamma-mathbbq-alpha-beta-given